# Show "Other Values" in Pandas Profiling Report

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-profiling

I am creating a Pandas Profiling Report. Under "Variable" detailed information of each column is displayed. When I press "Toggle details" and navigate to "categories" the most common values appear ending with "Other values" which are about 50% in my dataset. Is there a possibility to print all values in that report, so the other values are not combined?

Answer (score 2):

Set the amount of displayed rows (in this example 250):

`profile = ProfileReport(df, n_freq_table_max=250)`

Comment: Thank you. It should be noted that `n_freq_table_max` sets the number of categories in the tab "Categories" when you click "Toggle details". The number of categories in the simple Variable view (without clicking "Toggle details") stays as before.